# How to dynamically create GameObjects on the edges of the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've created a simple script that allows me to create and position 4 different GameObjects with RigidBody2D and BoxCollider2D to fit the chosen camera size and aspect. The problem is: after the game objects creation, the scene looks similar to this:

[image: Dynamically created walls.]

Unfortunately, my gameplay requires that the edges of this screen are covered with similar GameObjects with 45° angles. This is necessary to avoid my player from getting stuck while bouncing on the walls and corners.

[image: Dynamically created corners.]

How can I dynamically create this objects, set to 45° rotation on each of them and position it on the corners of the screen? This is what I have so far:

```
topWall.size = new Vector2 (mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.width * 2f, 0f, 0f)).x, 1f);
topWall.center = new Vector2 (0f, mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 ( 0f, Screen.height, 0f)).y + 0.5f);

bottomWall.size = new Vector2 (mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.width * 2, 0f, 0f)).x, 1f);
bottomWall.center = new Vector2 (0f, mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 0f)).y - 0.5f);

leftWall.size = new Vector2(1f, mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, Screen.height*2f, 0f)).y);;
leftWall.center = new Vector2(mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)).x - 0.5f, 0f);

rightWall.size = new Vector2(1f, mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, Screen.height*2f, 0f)).y);
rightWall.center = new Vector2(mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, 0f, 0f)).x + 0.5f, 0f);
```

**This is the script used to create the four red walls on the first image. How can I modify this to create squares, rotate them and position on the corners?**

Thank you!

Comment: Okay, this is what you have, but what is it that doesn't work? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: " i need to find a way to make another 4 in the edges of the camera with 45° to avoid my player from getting stuck."?

Comment: Okay, assuming the upper right corner is at coordinates 10x10, if you create another 'wall' that goes from 8x10 to 10x8 you have a 45° wall in the upper right corner. Is that what you are asking, the coordinates that you need for the angled walls?